# swifty json crashing a lot

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I am using SwiftyJSON to parse json responses from the server.

The app is crashing a lot (getting reports on crashlytics) but I can't seem to figure out where they are happening.

The line of code all of the different point to is

```
let jsonDict = JSON(data: data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil)
```

this same line is used to parse all of the json responses for the different endpoints.

The basic code for doing these requests is:

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(
    req,
    queue: queue)
    { (res: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData! , err: NSError!) -> Void in
        let jsonDict = JSON(data: data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil) // and crashes on this line
```

There are no errors on the backend and the responses seem to be sending down 200 ok response code (although it is hard to match this up)

is there a way I can put a try catch around this line so it doesn't crash the app?

heres a screen from crashlytics [image: screenshot crashlytics (fabric)]

Comment: You should make use of the `error` parm and, in concert with that, check for a NIL result.

Comment: Are you sure the crash is in the JSON parsing and not in the callback? IIRC, EXC_BREAKPOINT happens when you break a Swift contract (nullable, typecast, ..)

Comment: @HotLicks is correct. You need to check the server call worked before attempting to parse the data. Besides the things he mentioned, also check the response status code.

Comment: @MikeTaverne - I was speaking of checking result from the JSON parse.  The parser returns NIL if the parse fails.

Comment: @HotLicks - I misunderstood you. But the OP claims the crash is occurring on the line that parses the JSON.

Comment: @MikeTaverne - Yes, and what happens on that line if nil is returned?

Comment: I would expect jsonDict to be nil. I don't see why app would crash on this line.

Comment: so if JSON returns nil it would crash on that line?

Answer (score 0):

You should figure out why it's crashing instead of trying to mask the issue via do/try/catch. Start by removing the backend call and feed a sample JSON that's representative of what the server will return to your JSON call and see if it crashes there.